# Text showing up in cout stream that is not put there in the first place?

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code for an assignment.  It "mostly" works, but I get some very strange issues.

Whenever I use cout <<, there are characters included in it that cannot possibly be from the current iteration of the program.

Below, you can see "Error:  Close tag: " and "rror:  Close tag:" in the cout output, but the code that does this never gets executed, at least according to VS2015 and my breakpoint.

[image: Debug Output]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node *next = NULL;
    string tag{};
    int occurrences = 0;
};

class Stack
{
private:
    Node *top = NULL;

public:
    void Push(string inTag);
    void Pop();
    string Peek();
};

void output(fstream & stream, string output)
{
    cout << output << endl;
    stream << output << endl;
}

void pause()
{
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    char dummy[1]{};
    cin.getline(dummy, 1);
}

class Tag
{

private:
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    string tag{};
    int occurrences = 0;

public:

    // AddTag that doesn't care about occurrences (for empty elements tags)
    void AddTag(string inTag)
    {
        // List empty
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            curr = new Node;
            curr->next = NULL;
            curr->tag = inTag;
            head = curr;
            tail = curr;
            return;
        }

        // List populated - inTag becomes new head
        if (head->tag > inTag)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            curr = new Node;
            curr->next = head;
            curr->tag = inTag;
            head = curr;
            return;
        }

        // List populated - inTag becomes new tail
        if (tail->tag <= inTag)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            curr = new Node;
            curr->next = NULL;
            curr->tag = inTag;
            tail->next = curr;
            tail = curr;
            return;
        }

        // List populated - inTag goes somewhere in between
        if (head->tag < inTag && tail->tag > inTag)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            Node *temp = NULL;
            temp = new Node;
            temp->tag = inTag;

            curr = head;
            while (curr != NULL && inTag > curr->tag && inTag > curr->next->tag)
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            temp->next = curr->next;
            curr->next = temp;

        }

    }

    // Searches through linked list, returns pointer if tag found
    Node* findTag(string inTag)
    {
        if (head == NULL) { return NULL; } // If list is empty we know it's not there

        Node *curr = NULL;
        curr = head;

        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            if (curr->tag == inTag) // We found it
            {
                return curr;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        // We didn't find it
        return NULL;

    }

    // AddTag that takes into account occurrences, for unique HTML tags
    void AddUniqueTag(string inTag)
    {
        // Tag found, update the occurrences for that tag
        Node *found = NULL;
        found = findTag(inTag);
        if (found != NULL)
        {
            found->occurrences++;
            return;
        }

        // Tag not found, proceed with creating new node
        // List empty
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            curr = new Node;
            curr->next = NULL;
            curr->tag = inTag;
            curr->occurrences = 1;
            head = curr;
            tail = curr;
            return;
        }

        // List populated - inTag becomes new head
        if (head->tag > inTag)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            curr = new Node;
            curr->next = head;
            curr->tag = inTag;
            curr->occurrences = 1;
            head = curr;
            return;
        }

        // List populated - inTag becomes new tail
        if (tail->tag <= inTag)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            curr = new Node;
            curr->next = NULL;
            curr->tag = inTag;
            curr->occurrences = 1;
            tail->next = curr;
            tail = curr;
            return;
        }

        // List populated - inTag goes somewhere in between
        if (head->tag < inTag && tail->tag > inTag)
        {
            Node *curr = NULL;
            Node *temp = NULL;
            temp = new Node;
            temp->tag = inTag;
            temp->occurrences = 1;

            curr = head;
            while (curr != NULL && inTag > curr->tag && inTag > curr->next->tag)
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            temp->next = curr->next;
            curr->next = temp;

        }

    }

    void outputList(fstream & outFile)
    {
        Node *curr = NULL;
        curr = head;

        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            output(outFile, "Node tag: " + curr->tag + "    Node occurrences: " + to_string(curr->occurrences) + '\n');
            curr = curr->next;
        }

    }

};

void Stack::Push(string inTag)
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        top = new Node;
        top->next = NULL;
        top->tag = inTag;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->next = top;
        temp->tag = inTag;
        top = temp;
    }

}

void Stack::Pop()
{
    //Empty stack
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Could not pop:  There were no elements on the stack." << endl;
        return;
    }

    //Stack contains multiple elements
    else if (top->next != NULL)
    {
        Node *next = top->next;
        delete top;
        top = next;
    }

    //Stack contains one element
    else if (top->next == NULL)
    {
        delete top;
        top = NULL;
    }
}

string Stack::Peek()
{
    //Empty stack
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return "";
    }
    //Stack contains any number of elements
    else
    {
        return top->tag;
    }
}



int main()
{
    Stack myStack;
    Tag emptyElementTags;
    Tag uniqueTags;

    fstream logFile;
    logFile.open("log.txt", ios::app);
    if (!logFile)
    {
        cout << "Unrecoverable Error:  Log file not accessible." << endl;
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    fstream HTMLOutput;
    HTMLOutput.open("HTMLOutput.txt", ios::out);
    if (!HTMLOutput)
    {
        output(logFile, "Unrecoverable Error:  HTML output file not accessible.\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    fstream emptyElement;
    emptyElement.open("EmptyElementTags.dat", ios::in);
    if (!emptyElement)
    {
        output(logFile, "Unrecoverable Error:  Empty element file not accessible.\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    // Check to see if empty element file is empty
    emptyElement.seekg(0, emptyElement.end);

    int filePos; // Added
    filePos = emptyElement.tellg();

    if (filePos == 0)
    {
        output(logFile, "Unrecoverable Error:  Empty element file is empty.\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    emptyElement.seekg(0, emptyElement.beg);


    fstream HTMLFile1;
    HTMLFile1.open("File1.html", ios::in);
    if (!HTMLFile1)
    {
        output(logFile, "Unrecoverable Error:  HTML file 1 not accessible.\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    // Check to see if HTML file 1 is empty
    HTMLFile1.seekg(0, HTMLFile1.end);

    filePos = HTMLFile1.tellg();

    if (filePos == 0)
    {
        output(logFile, "Unrecoverable Error:  HTML file 1 is empty.\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    HTMLFile1.seekg(0, HTMLFile1.beg);

    fstream HTMLFile2;
    HTMLFile2.open("File2.html", ios::in);
    if (!HTMLFile2)
    {
        cout << "Unrecoverable Error:  HTML file 2 not accessible." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HTMLFile2.seekg(0, HTMLFile2.end);

    filePos = HTMLFile2.tellg();

    if (filePos == 0)
    {
        output(logFile, "Unrecoverable Error:  HTML file 2 is empty.\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    HTMLFile2.seekg(0, HTMLFile2.beg);

    string inEmptyElement{ " " };
    while (std::getline(emptyElement, inEmptyElement))
    {
        emptyElementTags.AddTag(inEmptyElement);
    }

    string readHTML{ " " };
    string readTag = "";

    int tagLoc = 0;
    int lineLoc = 0;

    while (std::getline(HTMLFile1, readHTML))
    {
        lineLoc++;
        output(HTMLOutput, lineLoc + " " + readHTML);

        for (int i = 0; i < readHTML.length(); i++)
        {
            // We found a tag specifier, start reading text
            if (readHTML[i] == '<')
            {
                tagLoc = i;
                bool closeTag = false;

                i++; // Move to the next character

                // Check to see if it's a close tag.
                if (readHTML[i] == '/')
                {
                    closeTag = true;
                    i++;
                }

                // Read while we are reading letters (no symbols or whitespace
                while((readHTML[i] >= 65 && readHTML[i] <= 90) || (readHTML[i] >= 97 && readHTML[i] <= 122) || (readHTML[i] >= 48 && readHTML[i] <= 57))
                {
                    readTag.push_back(readHTML[i]);
                    i++;
                }

                if (readTag.length() > 0)
                {

                    if (closeTag == true)
                    {
                        // Matching tag was on the stack, so we pop it off.
                        if (myStack.Peek() == readTag)
                        {
                            myStack.Pop();

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            output(logFile, "Error:  Close tag: ");
                            output(logFile, "</" + readTag + ">");
                            output(logFile, " did not match what was on the stack.  Skipping.\n");
                            output(logFile, "Line: " + to_string(lineLoc) + "    Character: " + to_string(tagLoc + 1) + "\n");

                            cout << "Error:  Close tag: </" << readTag << "> did not match what was on the stack.  Skipping." << endl;
                            cout << "Line: " << to_string(lineLoc) << "    Character: " << to_string(tagLoc + 1) << endl;
                        }

                        closeTag = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        uniqueTags.AddUniqueTag(readTag);               
                        myStack.Push(readTag);
                    }



                }
                else
                {
                    output(logFile, "Error:  Tag at line " + to_string(lineLoc) + " character " + to_string(tagLoc + 1) + "contained no letters.\n");
                }

            }

            readTag.clear();        

        }


    }

    //emptyElementTags.outputList();
    uniqueTags.outputList(HTMLOutput);

    cout << "We're done." << endl;
    pause();
    return 0;

}
```

Any ideas on what the cause could be?

Comment: Typically when this happens, it's because you are running code you didn't think you were running - for example there is a compile error in your code that you ignored, and you are running the old version...

Comment: Thanks, agreed.  I thought that too, which is why I rebuilt the code and relaunched VS2015.  Unfortunately no dice. :(

Comment: That is a *lot* of code. Please try cutting it down, you may also very well find the answer while doing so.

Comment: `cin.getline(dummy, 1);` is a weird thing to do

Comment: the section of code with `if (readHTML[i] == '<')` may cause buffer overflows. Every time you do `i++` you also need to check you haven't gotten to the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks M.M.  The dummy getline is old code that I had in there before I wrote my pause() function.  With regard to i++, I just put in if statements so that the i++s will only be executed if i < readHTML.length(), but unfortunately, no dice, unless I should try going about it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In this line:

```
output(HTMLOutput, lineLoc + " " + readHTML);
```

lineLoc is an integer.  I needed a to_string:

```
output(HTMLOutput, to_string(lineLoc) + " " + readHTML);
```

I guess weird things can happen when you try to use operator+ with an integer, a const char and a string!

Comment: not weird, just regular C style pointer arithmetic. Of course it does become a little weird [and undefined] when you go outside the string and pick up a "random" string after the string you were adding to. But `"Hello, World"+7` is `"World"` and perfectly valid C or C++ code, and `7 + "Hello, World"` does the exact same thing.

Comment: You're right.  Interesting, I did not know you could do that.  Off to research pointer arithmetic.